# Запятая перед словом «что»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

*А никто не заметил что слово «ужасом» пишется через О?*

Нужно ли ставить запятую после слова «заметил»? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Это сложноподчиненное предложение, в котором между главным предложением (*А никто не заметил*) и придаточным (*слово «ужасом» пишется через «О»*) по правилам ставится запятая (перед подчинительным союзом "что").
Вопросительная интонация в этом предложении на пунктуацию не влияет.

*А никто не заметил, **что** слово «ужасом» пишется через «О»?*

Из Нацкорпуса РЯ:
*Никто не заметил, **что** я убежал из дома...* (В. Каверин);
*И никто не заметил, **что** они совсем не знают немецкого языка* (Л. Гурова);
*Никто не заметил, **что** принцесса не ночевала у себя в комнате* (Д. Сабитова).

[Общая характеристика сложноподчинённых предложений](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/735-21_obschaya_harakteristika_slozhnopodchinennyh_predlozhenii.html)

*Никто не заметил,

**Что** кошка в лукошке

Хихикает тихо

И чмокает лихо*!
Юнна Мориц. Малиновая кошка

*Никто не заметил, **что** вы похудели?* [заголовок статьи]

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснение!!!